# How to limit the number of items displayed in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this Django model in my newspaper app:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

It currently displays all articles but I want to limit what is displayed to the 3 most recent articles. How is that done?

This is my view:

```
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

This is the html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  {% for article in object_list %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ article.title }}</span> &middot;
        <span class="text-muted">by {{ article.author }} | {{ article.date }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        {% for comment in article.comments.all %}
          <p>
            <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ comment.author }} &middot;</span>
            {{ comment }}
          </p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
<br />
  {% endfor %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What displays all articles?  We need to see your view function at a minimum.

Comment: Show the view that is handling the query of this model

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to Django so wasn't sure what I needed to include. Added the view and html now.

Comment: @JackMoody no this question has nothing to do with ansible

Comment: @JackMoody in the context of django, it is not misleading at all. While django uses jinja2 (or some variant of it), it does not handle the limiting of elements with jinja

Comment: @ritlew I probably should have spent more time looking for a better fit. I believe this question has been answered with [Only show the latest 3 posts in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928866/only-show-the-latest-3-posts-in-django).

Comment: Yes and no. That would have been the correct answer until the OP added more information which would make it incorrect. The current upvoted answer is exactly what OP wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your (assumed) `ListView` you should define the `queryset`, something like

```
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
        model = Article
        template_name = 'article_list.html'
        login_url = 'login'
        queryset = Article.objects.order_by('-date')[:3]
```

[More on this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects).